# Setup Eclipse EGit to Push to Windows Share Over SSH

Tags: java, git, eclipse, ssh, egit

I am new to git, and version control in general, and am trying to implement it for my team of three developers. We are the only developers for our agency.

I am trying to make the setup as simple as possible to just get the ball rolling. My plan is that we will use EGIT in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite), with each person running off a local repository for developing and then pushing to a remote repository on a Windows share. I was planning to use SSH to facilitate push/pull between our work PCs and the Server so that I do not have to do any site setup and it seemed easiest while still having authentication.

I have added EGit to Eclipse on my work PC and followed the process to getting a project shared and having the initial commit on my local repository.

I installed OpenSSH on my Windows 2012R2 server, installed Git on it, and initiated a bare repository inside a folder in the share I wish to use as the remote repository.

Here is my remote repository setup in Eclipse:

```
URI: ssh://domain\user@server:22/share/git/repositories
Host: server
Repository path: share/git/repositories
Protocol: ssh
Port: 22
Authentication: currently using username and password, will eventually switch to SSH key once I get things working
```

When I try to run the preview I get the following error:

```
"Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs. 'ssh://domain\user@server:22/share/git/repositories": 'git-upload-pack' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

I'd appreciate help and recommendations to getting things going in a basic setup.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have git installed in the server?... and if it is, is it properly configured so that it is reachable through the `$PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I installed git on the server and used the Git CLI to initiate the bare repository.

By "reachable through the $Path" I am assuming you are asking if the environment variable is set? I have both "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" and "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\" in the server's Path environment variable.

Comment: The error message (`'git-upload-pack' is not recognized...`) indicates a faulty installation, such that the command interpreter on the destination system can't find the installed Git. Whether that means that Git is installed in the *wrong place*, or whether it means that the ssh *server* is misconfigured, depends on how you want the server to work. I don't set up Windows servers (ever: I avoid Windows as much as I can) so I can't go past this sort of general comment, though.

Comment: @torek If I ssh to the server from my PC's command line and then type in "git" I receive the list of available commands. Doing the same directly on my PC's command line and on the server's command line produces the same result.

Comment: But if you ssh in *as Git*, what happens? If you ssh in as yourself, presumably you get your own path setup. (This smells like a Windows registry issue to me, but again, I don't "do" Windows.)

Comment: @torek Was I supposed to setup a Git user? Sorry, I'm completely new to this. In my example URI in eclipse, the user I used was my domain user, so I figured it would be doing things as my account.

Comment: Depends on the desired setup. But: if you're planning to log in as yourself, and `git-upload-pack` isn't being found but `git` is, this just means that your personal setup doesn't have the `git-upload-pack` program in its path. There was some confusion, briefly, at one point as to whether this was supposed to be `git upload-pack` or `git-upload-pack` but it should be installed under `git-upload-pack` in the same place as the `git` binary.

Comment: Note that `git foo` actually invokes `git-foo` "under the covers", as it were, so in general there's a hyphen variety of each command installed *somewhere*. But most of them are in the (separate) `git --exec-path` location. The confusion over the hyphenated `git-upload-pack` was whether all shell users would be able to find the command if it were spelled without the hyphen (and the answer is "no", so `git-upload-pack` has to continue to exist in the same place as `git`).

Comment: Windows might be different here, but note that on a Unix-ish system, `ssh host` to get an interactive shell, followed by running `program`, can often be different from `ssh host program`: the former invokes a *non-interactive* shell on the given host and that non-interactive shell may (e.g.) read `.profile` but not `.bashrc`, while the interactive one might read both. The details depend on the user's shell, and potentially more.